# Spring Boot @Cachebale annotation not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, groovy

I'm currently implementing Spring cache for some of our methods in production. It worked well with a REST controller method using `@GetMapping`, which makes a call to a service method annotated with `@Cacheable`.

However, when I tried to implement the same caching mechanism in Groovy scripts, it doesn't seem to work. ChatGPT suggested that this might be because the method call annotated with `@Cacheable` in the service happens from the constructor of the component.

To investigate further, I created a test Spring Boot app and attempted to call a test method with `@Cacheable` from another bean's method annotated with `@PostConstruct`, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. After reading several manuals and documentation, I suspect that no proxy is being created or something similar.

Here is the code for my test app:

```
package test.spring.springtest;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTestApplication {
    private final JavaStarter javaStarter;

    public SpringTestApplication(JavaStarter javaStarter) {
        this.javaStarter = javaStarter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void invokeJavaStarterMethod() {
        javaStarter.invokeTestMethod("test");
    }
}
```

```
package test.spring.springtest.config;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("cache");
    }
}
```

```
package test.spring.springtest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import test.spring.springtest.service.JavaService;

@Component
public class JavaStarter {

    private final JavaService javaService;

    JavaStarter(JavaService javaService) {
        this.javaService = javaService;
    }

    public void invokeTestMethod(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + javaService.testMethod(input));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package test.spring.springtest.service;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class JavaService {
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "cache")
    public String testMethod(String input) {
        System.out.println("Cache is not being used");
        return input;
    }
}
```

Could you please explain why the caching behavior is not working as expected?

In my project, I decided to implement caching using the `@Cacheable` annotation in my Spring Boot application. The caching worked perfectly when I applied it to a REST controller method that called a service method annotated with `@Cacheable`.

However, when I attempted to use the same caching mechanism in my Groovy scripts, it didn't have the desired effect. I even tried calling a test method with `@Cacheable` from another bean's method using `@PostConstruct`, but that didn't solve the issue either.

I took the time to research various manuals and documentation to find a solution, but I couldn't figure out the underlying cause of the problem. It seems there might be a reason why the caching behavior isn't working as expected. It could be related to how I'm using the `@Cacheable` annotation or how it interacts with other components.

Comment: Please provide full code (including the packages and imports.

Comment: Can you try to clear the cache data by giving the following code snippet in CcaheConfig.                                                                                            
    @Autowired
    CacheManager cacheManager;                                                                              public void evictCaches() {
        cacheManager.getCacheNames()
            .forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());
    }

Comment: @RagaSGNur this code doesn't do anything. We need to call this method somehow, but I'm pretty sure it won't help anyway. On prod it works just fine w/o evicting anything.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot so the `@EnableCache` nor the cache configuration should be needed. All you should need is `spring.cache.type=SIMPLE` in your configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum commented out CacheConfig and put spring.cache.type=simple into application.properties but got thу same result. Cache is'nt working.

Comment: My bad you still need `@EnableCache` not the further confguration, you can just place it on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. But still it will not work, simply due to the class being injected into a class that is used very early on. It will receive an unproxied instance. If instead you use an `ApplicationRunner` and inject the `JavaStarter` into there, it will work.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the suggestion. After implementing ApplicationRunner cache works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually does work as expected.

The `@SpringBootApplication` is (indirectly but eventually) an `@Configuration` class. Those are processed very early in the process. As you are injecting it into an `@Configuration` class no proxying for beans has taken place (as we are still in the reading configuration phase) and thus no caching will take place.

You can see this if you would add an `ApplicationRunner` which invokes the method as well.

```java
package biz.deinum.stackoverflow.caching;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class StackoverflowCachingApplication {

  private final JavaStarter javaStarter;

  public StackoverflowCachingApplication(JavaStarter javaStarter) {
    this.javaStarter = javaStarter;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowCachingApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public ApplicationRunner invoker(JavaStarter starter) {
    return (args) -> starter.invokeTestMethod("test");
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void invokeJavaStarterMethod() {
    javaStarter.invokeTestMethod("test");
  }
}
```

If you run this the output will be something like the following

```bash
2024-03-04T16:05:36.663+01:00  INFO 3105 --- [           main] b.d.s.c.StackoverflowCachingApplication  : Starting StackoverflowCachingApplication using Java 23-ea with PID 3105 (/Users/BV38BY/Downloads/stackoverflow-caching/target/classes started by BV38BY in /Users/BV38BY/Downloads/stackoverflow-caching)
2024-03-04T16:05:36.664+01:00  INFO 3105 --- [           main] b.d.s.c.StackoverflowCachingApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Cache is not being used
Output: test

Cache is not being used
Output: test

Cache is not being used
Output: test

2024-03-04T16:05:36.920+01:00  INFO 3105 --- [           main] b.d.s.c.StackoverflowCachingApplication  : Started StackoverflowCachingApplication in 0.385 seconds (process running for 0.618)
Cache is not being used
Output: test

Output: test

Output: test
```

As you see the first output is from the `@PostConstruct` and also is printed before the `Starter ...`  line. The one from the `ApplicationRunner` is invoked after that and the caching and proxying has been properly setup.